# How to remove Trailing Zero from milliseconds in DATETIME in MySQL

Tags: mysql

How can I remove trailing zeros occurring in higher precision of DATETIME in MySQL.

Sample input/output:

```
2018-04-13 13:02:32.948000     =>    2018-04-13 13:02:32.948
```

Comment: MySQL never give DateTime result with trailing zero, in the result, it will automatically be discarded. can you give any example where it is giving trailing zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you output the `DATETIME` value with milliseconds directly MySQL removes the trailing zeros.

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    colDateTime DATETIME(6)
);

INSERT INTO test VALUES ('2018-04-17 11:12:13.444000');
```

Now we use the following `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT * FROM test; -- output: 2018-04-17T11:12:13.444Z (0 at the end are removed by MySQL).
```

The only way you get the zeros at the end is using the [`DATE_FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(colDateTime, '%f') FROM test; -- output: 444000
```

In this case you can [`TRIM`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) the zero of this string value:

```
SELECT TRIM(TRAILING '0' FROM DATE_FORMAT(colDateTime, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s.%f')) FROM test;
```

> **demo:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b0655f/5/2

Answer (score 0):

Based on the MySQL-Doc there should be a "fsp" parameter for DATETIME-fields.

```
CREATE TABLE fractest( c1 TIME(2), c2 DATETIME(2), c3 TIMESTAMP(2) );

mysql> INSERT INTO fractest VALUES ('17:51:04.777', '2014-09-08 17:51:04.777', '2014-09-08 17:51:04.777');

mysql> SELECT * FROM fractest;
+-------------+------------------------+------------------------+
| c1          | c2                     | c3                     |
+-------------+------------------------+------------------------+
| 17:51:04.78 | 2014-09-08 17:51:04.78 | 2014-09-08 17:51:04.78 |
+-------------+------------------------+------------------------+
```

But it's not possible to remove trailing zeros dynamically you have to fix the length of the fractional seconds precision.

Source: [Fractional Seconds in Time Values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fractional-seconds.html)